# Foreach if loop

Tags: r, loops, foreach, bigdata

I have a dataset that is 60 million rows and want to compute a comparison on every row. It's the simple time difference between two time stamps. To benchmark running time, I did the calculation on 1 million rows and it took almost 2 minutes. I'm hoping there is a faster way.

Here is some example data.

```
library(data.table)

DT <- fread( 'unique_id,click_time,click_time2
100005361,2017-11-09 03:58:32,2017-11-09 03:59:33
100005372,2017-11-09 00:53:08,2017-11-09 00:53:40
100005373,2017-11-09 04:38:52,2017-11-09 04:38:53
100005374,2017-11-09 05:42:30,2017-11-09 05:44:30' )
```

This is the basic metric I want to compute:

```
DT$click_diff = difftime(DT$click_time,DT$click_time2,units=c("secs"))
```

If I just run this I think it will take hours upon hours, so I tried to use the foreach() package, but I think I'm making a mistake.

```
library(doParallel)
library(foreach)
cl <- makeCluster(parallel::detectCores()-1)
registerDoParallel(cl)   #create a cluster


r <-  foreach(i=1:nrow(DT) %dopar% {

results[i] = difftime(DT$click_time[i],DT$click_time_2[i],units=c("secs"))

return(data.frame(results))
}

parallel::stopCluster(cl)
```

The clusters are definitely set up but nothing is happening. Does anyone have any advice on how to fix this code or perhaps another way of speeding up the time difference calculation for a large data set?

Comment: If you want to parallelize the computation through several worker, you must assign each worker the work to do for you. This means that you need to use a primary key to split you data in chunks and each chunk will be computed by one of the workers!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you take advantage of the fact that R simply represents time as seconds since a given time (midnight of January 1st, 1970 by default) this should take a trivial amount of time single threaded.

Generate the data:

```
library(data.table)

## Generate Data
RowCount <- 60e6
DT <- data.table(unique_id = seq_len(RowCount),
                 click_time = sample.int(1e5,size = RowCount, replace = TRUE),
                 duration = sample.int(1e2,size = RowCount, replace = TRUE))

DT[,click_time2 := click_time + duration]
DT[,duration := NULL]

DT[, click_time := as.POSIXct(click_time, tz = "UTC", origin = "1970-01-01 00:00:00")]
DT[, click_time2 := as.POSIXct(click_time2, tz = "UTC", origin = "1970-01-01 00:00:00")]


head(DT)
#    unique_id          click_time         click_time2
# 1:         1 1970-01-01 04:50:25 1970-01-01 04:51:08
# 2:         2 1970-01-02 00:53:50 1970-01-02 00:54:43
# 3:         3 1970-01-01 15:58:54 1970-01-01 15:59:18
# 4:         4 1970-01-01 22:36:32 1970-01-01 22:37:48
# 5:         5 1970-01-01 08:51:48 1970-01-01 08:52:17
# 6:         6 1970-01-01 12:24:15 1970-01-01 12:24:30
```

Calculate `duration`:

```
system.time({
  DT[,duration := as.integer(click_time2) - as.integer(click_time) ]
})

# user  system elapsed 
# 0.700   0.069   0.772
```

> Question: even if you keep the `difftime` class and don't use data.table syntax this should still take a trivial amount of time. Is your computer running out of memory?

```
system.time({
  DT$click_diff = difftime(DT$click_time,DT$click_time2,units=c("secs"))
})

#   user  system elapsed 
#  1.796   0.653   2.452 

head(DT)
#    unique_id          click_time         click_time2 duration
# 1:         1 1970-01-01 21:27:49 1970-01-01 21:29:00  71 secs
# 2:         2 1970-01-01 16:56:37 1970-01-01 16:58:04  87 secs
# 3:         3 1970-01-01 16:30:53 1970-01-01 16:31:28  35 secs
# 4:         4 1970-01-01 21:00:30 1970-01-01 21:01:57  87 secs
# 5:         5 1970-01-01 17:27:53 1970-01-01 17:28:19  26 secs
# 6:         6 1970-01-01 07:52:49 1970-01-01 07:53:19  30 secs
```

Comment: This works great, thank you. The issue was the column was input as class character. Using the library fasttime I was able to convert them very quickly and then the subtraction was almost instant.

Comment: Glad you got it worked out, `fasttime` is a pretty awesome little package when you're lucky enough to have source data with a valid input format!